# When localization is an integral extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

> Let $A$ be an integral domain. If the localization $A_S$ is integral over $A$ then it equals to $A$.

I can prove the case that $A$ is integrally closed by using definition. However, how to deal with general case ? I appreciate it if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: How can you prove $\;A\;$ is int. closed *in the general case*? This is not true in general, though it is true if $\;A\;$ is a UFD, say. Anyway, what is $\;S\;$ ? **Any** multiplicatively closed subset of $\;A\;$?

Comment: yes,$S$ is multiplicatively closed subset of $A$

Comment: i think $A$ contained in $A_S$ ,and $A_S$ contained in Frac($A$) so if $A$ is integrally closed we have $A_S$ contained in A so we get $A$ equals $A_S$ .Is there something wrong? @DonAntonio

Comment: Nothing at all ... **if** .... $\;A\;$ is integrally closed . The problem is that this is false for general integral domains, that's all. I think what has to be done here is to use only the fact that $\;A_S/A\;$ is an integral extension...

Comment: Show that every $s\in S$ is invertible by using that $1/s$ is integral over $A$.

Comment: That's right .Thanks a lot