# Ring of fractions of $R$ is integral over $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $S\subseteq R$ be a multiplicative closed subset containing 1.

> I need to show that if $S^{-1}R$ is integral over $R$, then $S^{-1}R=R$.

I don't see how to get started.

Comment: Let $s \in S$. Use the fact that $1/s$ is integral over $R$ to show that $s$ is in fact a unit in $R$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290380/when-localization-is-an-integral-extension)

Comment: For integral extensions $R \subset T$, we have $R^* = T^* \cap R$.

Comment: The correct statement is the following: if $S^{-1}R$ is integral over $R$, then the canonical homomorphism $R\to S^{-1}R$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

One direction is because $R\subset S^{-1}R$. Now if $ 1/s$ is integral over $R$, then it satisfies: $$ \frac{1}{s^n} +\frac{ a_{n-1}}{s^{n-1}} +\cdots+\frac{a_0}{1} = \frac01 $$ where $ a_i \in R$. Now thus we have $ 1 = -\sum_{i=0}^n s^{n-i}a_i  \implies s(-\sum_{i=0}^n s^{n-1-i}a_i)= 1 \implies s$ is a unit in $R$. (If $s^ka_i = 0$ for all $i$, where $k < n$, then we get $1/s^{k-n} = 0$  which is not possible.) Thus $ 1/s \in R$. Thus $S^{-1}R \subset R$. Combining these two we get $S^{-1}R =R $.

Comment: We identify the elements of R  , $r$ in $S^{-1}R$ by $r/1$.and thus that's trivial and the remaining part also doesn't involve any integral case. I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Ok i got the argument , i hope i have rectified it.

Comment: In general, $R$ is not necessarily contained in $S^{-1}R$. However, if one supposes that the canonical morphism $R\to S^{-1}R$ is injective, then $S$ contains only non-zerodivisors, and in this case your answer is correct. (What you missed is the following: $a/s=0/1$ is not necessarily equivalent to $a=0$.)